# fine-uploader handle custom data in response JSON

Tags: json, fine-uploader

Hopefully this is simple issues, where I have obviously missed something in the RTFM.

I have an application I am integrating Fine Uploader, and I have it working now in terms of uploading files to the server. The only issue is that I need to take some action on the client side each time the user successfully uploads a file.

In short I would like to have a hidden input field with a comma separated list of files which have been successfully been uploaded.

In my JSON response from my server side implementation. I am of course including "success: true". In addition I have a entry called "file: /path/to/savedUpload.file".

So when an upload is performed successfully, I just need to know how to call my own method with the json response passed in so I can take care of managing the hidden input element.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!
Dustin

Comment: Could you clarify what the comma-separated values in the hidden input element are for?

If you simply want to take action on the client-side each time the user successfully uploads a file, then you can put some logic inside of [the `complete` event](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#complete):

Comment: Mark,I think I may have just answered my own question. The RTFM was a little unclear to me. But digging into the JQeury stuff directly I think this solved my problem. `$("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '/upload/endpoint'
    }
}).on('error', function (event, id, name, reason) {
    // do something
}).on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
    // do something
});
`

Comment: what was unclear about the documentation?

Comment: sorry.. edited my comment above to be complete... as far as unclear.. I thought it was unclear about how to handle on complete/error events... I think I probably just needed to read more carefully...

Comment: Mind putting your solution as an answer for others who may have similar issues?

Comment: It wont let me for 7 more hours... I will try to remember and post it later today.

Comment: I sturggled finding the RTFM for how to do this because it was nested in the JQuery section.

For others, the answer is:

    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '/upload/endpoint'
        }
    }).on('error', function (event, id, name, reason) {
        // do something
    }).on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
        // THIS IS WHERE I PUT MY LOGIC TO MANAGE THE HIDDEN INPUT ELEMENT
    });

Comment: @DustinM Can you add your resolution as an answer when you get a chance?